# How to get exit code from remote machine using sshpass command

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I want to list the files on the remote machine using bash script without entering password.

I am using following command to do it

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ubuntusite.net  "ls /usr/local/"
```

I want to get the exit code from the above command to know my command (ls /usr/local) fails or get passed.

How to do it? Kindly help me

Comment: Why are you using sshpass rather than passwordless RSA/DSA keys?

Comment: And [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) either.

Comment: Can you give us some context for this? Where does the above command fit into a larger script? A bigger picture will help us provide more appropriate answers.

Comment: There are indeed use cases for `sshpass`. Also using `ls` in scripts is perfectly okay for testing or for output. It can well be a placeholder for a more useful command. I'm pretty sure the OP simply asked how to get the return value of ls through to the calling shell when using `sshpass`.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
[STEP 101] # sshpass ssh 127.0.0.1 true
[STEP 102] # echo $?
0
[STEP 103] # sshpass ssh 127.0.0.1 false
[STEP 104] # echo $?
1
[STEP 105] # sshpass ssh 127.0.0.1 exit 11
[STEP 106] # echo $?
11
[STEP 107] #
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you clearly, you need not `ls` output, just only exit code, right?

So, try this:

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ubuntusite.net  "ls /usr/local/ &>/dev/null && echo $? || echo 1"
```

It will return and print `0` if command passed, print `1` in another case.

Comment: Is there way to display error messages when failure?

Comment: I don't get output as 1 if ssh password or ssh username or url is wrong.